# Show that there are two different ordered bases

Tags: linear-algebra

everyone forgive the inconveniences I have this problem

Let $V$ a complex vector space of finite dimension $T$ a operator over $V$. Show that there are two different ordered bases, $\beta$ and  $\beta ^ {'}$ of $V$ such that if $A$ is the matrix $T$ for $\beta$ and if $A ^ {'}$ is the matrix $T$ for $ \beta'$ then $A ^ {'} = A$.

Thanks for your help :D

Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can prove something a bit stronger. Given any fixed basis $\mathcal{B}$, we can find another basis $\mathcal{B}'$ such that $A = A'$.

Let $\mathcal{B}$ and hence $A$ be given. The key is to find an invertible matrix which commutes with $A$. The obvious candidates are polynomials in $A$. Now, $B = A-\epsilon I$ is invertible for $\epsilon$ small enough, so suppose that we have some $\epsilon$ such that $$\det(A-\epsilon I)=\det(B)\neq 0$$ Let $B$ be the change of coordinates matrix from $\mathcal{B}$ to $\mathcal{B}'$. Then
$$BAB^{-1}=A'$$ 
But $B$ is a polynomial in $A$ and hence commutes with $A$, so
$$A' = BAB^{-1} = ABB^{-1} = A$$